# Chunk wise deleting data from database in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm, django-database

just say i fetched data in chunks from a table with 20 million entries and i need to process the whole data and need to delete **whole** data only once everything is processed (my condition is i cant delete inside the loop where it is getting fetched)

```
chunk = 10000
id_gte = 1
id_lt = 20000000
delete_query = MyModel.objects.none()
```

```
for i in range(id_gte, id_lt, chunk):
    data = MyModel.objects.filter(id__gte=i, id__lt=i+chunk)
    print(data)
    delete_query |= data
```

now if i want to delete the data...that i fetched in the loop, so i can do

```
delete_query.delete()
```

So my doubts are.

1. Does the **time** to delete the data that is deleted depends on that how much data i am deleting at once? Like above i am trying to delete the whole 20000000 rows at once. Will it be better to delete the data in chunks? Say in `delete_query`, i use a loop to get the **cached** chunks of queryset of size 10000 and delete them? So overall it will take maybe the same time, but it will **lock** the db for smaller times?
2. Does any evaluation done to delete the data from database? if yes, then is the query re-evaluated to delete the data. I mean in above code....does `delete_query.delete()` makes `delete_query` to get evaluated again, before deleting the data, or it will use the cache of `delete_query`.

Comment: Are you trying to delete everything from the table at once? If so then a `truncate` may perform better than a `delete`

Comment: no not everything. I cant use truncate.